# Downloading a file from S3 into a Zapier Task

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zapier

I would like to download a file from S3 in Zapier and use it (as file exists but not shown) in the rest of a Zap.  Strangely the S3 integration doesnt offer this (although you can do this in Box, Drive etc).

I guess we will need to use Code by Zapier and I have this basic JS - but I think I need to specify region and not sure how to link the output into Zap?

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update(
  {
    accessKeyId: ".. your key ..",
    secretAccessKey: ".. your secret key ..",
  }
);
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.getObject(
  { Bucket: "my-bucket", Key: "my-picture.jpg" },
  function (error, data) {
    if (error != null) {
      alert("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
    } else {
      alert("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes");
      // do something with data.Body
    }
  }
);
output = need to put my file here!!
```

I'd appreciate any pointers - I am surprised this has not been asked before - I hope it doesnt mean that I have missed something very obvious!

Answer (score 1):

Here is example to get json document from s3

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: ".. your key ..",
  secretAccessKey: ".. your secret key ..",
  region: "region",
});
var s3params = {
  Bucket: "bucket",
  Key: "key",
};
s3.getObject(s3params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  } else {
    let jsonString = data.Body.toString();
    let result = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    return result;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nonik - but I just get ReferenceError: AWS is not defined when I run on Zapier.  In my example using the SDK I dont get this - but instead I get an unexpected token!

Comment: I've fixed a syntax error in this answer. If you modify the `return result` line to be `return {output: result}`, it might work. Depends on what kind of file it is